# What is the right way to have namespaces in seperate files in C++?

Tags: c++, file, namespaces

What is the right way to have namespaces in other files so I can use them with `#include<>`

#### test.h

```cpp
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED

namespace numbers{
    const int foo = 8;
}

#endif //TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

However, I have also seen this

### test.h

```cpp
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED

namespace numbers{
    extern const int foo;
}

#endif //TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

### test.cpp

```cpp
#include "test.h"
namespace numbers{
    const int foo = 8;
}
```

and then the wherever I would want to use it ,

```cpp
#include "test.h"

std::cout << numbers::foo;
```

Both of them work, which is the correct way, and why?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with namespaces. It's about how to declare/define a global constant (which in your case happens to be inside a namespace). And the answer is both are correct.

Comment: @john is there any advantage in using one over the other?, if so you can add these things in an answer and I will happily accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first method you are going to get multiple definitions (assuming you have multiple includes), that's allowed because global constants are exempted from the One Definition Rule.

With the second method there is only one definition, in test.cpp.

The first method is more likely to lead to compiler optimisations because the compiler always knows the value of the constant, but if the object is expensive to construct it likely to be better to use the second method because there's no risk of having to construct multiple objects. Although even in that case the linker may well eliminate all but one of the objects.